# Actualización de valores en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo dos archivos principales. Tengo un Excel que contiene un formulario en el cuál se ponen indicadores diarios. Por otro lado tengo otro Excel que utiliza esos datos como recolección y análisis. Este segundo Excel, guarda datos de hasta un año, después se deberán poner los registros a 0 para que no se solapen los datos. Para ello he desarrollado una macro en mi formulario (que es quien gestiona también el día y mes en el que estamos) en el que vamos cada día de cada mes poniéndolo todo a 0. Hasta ahí bien. Todos los campos que dependen de mi formulario se actualizan correctamente a 0. El problema, es que en el libro que contiene la colección de todos los datos diarios, también tengo calculados una serie de promedios, que no se actualizan con el formulario, se actualizan con los datos de ese mismo fichero (el promedio de un mes por ejemplo). Esos promedios, en muchas ocasiones no se me actualizan a 0 cuando todos los demas valores están puestos a 0, es decir, conservan su valor anterior hasta que hagamos click en la fórmula y le demos al Enter (entonces ahí ya coge su valor real)

Alguien sabría resolver este pequeño problema? Esos datos pueden llevar a confusión y me gustaría no tener ese contratiempo.

[image: Ejemplo:]

El valor de Actual de Noviembre por ejemplo, está a 46. Ese valor es simplemente la suma de todos los días del mes en la tabla de arriba. Previamente esa suma valía 46, pero al actualizar los datos ya no vale eso, debería ser 0 también.

Comment: Has comprobado que el no se haya desactivado la opción de cálculo automático?

A veces Excel desactiva el cálculo automático, por ejemplo si la hoja es muy grande, para que cada vez que cambies algo el ordenador no se eternice actualizando todos los valores. 

Para activarlo de nuevo, en las opciones de Excel, según la versión:

Herramientas>Opciones>Calcular>Botón Office>Opciones de Excel>Fórmulas>Cálculo del libro

Comment: Sí, claro, tengo activado el cálculo automático del libro, y el cálculo iterativo para mis referencias circulares.

Comment: ¿Cómo está metido el 46 en la celda? ¿Cómo fórmula o como valor?

Comment: Está metido como fórmula. Como te digo, se debería actualizar junto con la suma de valores de la fila Actual de la primera tabla (la de los días del mes)

Answer (score 0):

No he encontrado una solución lo más eficiente posible, pero al menos me he quitado el problema de encima. He desarrollado 2 subrutinas en vba que limpien las tablas con 0s. Como tengo un formulario en el que pongo día y mes, simplemente me baso en pasar por todos los días del año con todos los valores a 0.

```
Sub borraMeses()
    For i = 1 To 13
        For j = 1 To 32
        Range("B6").Value = j
        Range("B7").Value = i
        Next j
        Next i     
End Sub
```

Esta rutina como digo, no acaba de solucionar el problema, ya que hay unos cuantos valores que no se actualizan (y no se por qué, parece que son los valores sacados con una fórmula que dependen de otra). Para ello he elaborado otra subrutina (esta ya es definitiva). Esta lo que hace es forzar el recalculado de todas las fórmulas de la hoja.

```
Sub ForzarCalculate()

Dim Celda As Range
For Each Celda In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
 Celda.Formula = Celda.Formula

Next
End Sub
```

Solucionar, se ha solucionado, y no causa demasiados problemas tener que ejecutar un par de subrutinas una vez al año, pero no es la solución ideal.